Definition of height of point in elliptic curves
I was reading this proof about Mordell's theorem. Here I stumbled across this definition of height of a rational point on an elliptic curve:

So how is this well defined? Take $P=(\frac{1}{2}, *)$ for this definition I would have $h(P) = \text{log}2$ which obviously is not an integer. Am I missing something?

This is probably a typo as the naive height is a function to the positive integers, but what they have written down is the logarithmic height (which is the log of the naive height)

@StevenCreech I see. Thank you
